# How do I run a regression with different variables in R using a loop?

Tags: r, loops, regression

I want to estimate the following regression models:

```
y <- rnorm(1:100)
x1 <- 1:100
x2 <- 1:100
x3 <- 1:100

my_data <- data.frame(cbind(y, x1, x2, x3))

m1 <- lm(y ~ x1, data = my_data)
m2 <- lm(y ~ x2, data = my_data)
m3 <- lm(y ~ x3, data = my_data)
```

I want to run several models like this, using the same dataset and a different independent variable in each model. How can I use a loop to run each model?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily accomplished using the `apply()` function:

```
data_to_analyse <- my_data[, -1] # leave out the y column for this analysis

out <- apply(data_to_analyse, 2, function(current_col){

lm.out <- lm(my_data$y ~ current_col)

})
```

This takes each column of the data.frame  ("current_col") and then performs linear regression. The output of the function is a list containing the results of each regression, each entry named by the variable name.

Comment: For easier comparison, you could `broom::tidy` the output before placing it in a list, and then `dplyr::bind_rows` to get one dataframe with all your results. Be sure to include `.id = "name"` in your `bind_rows` to be able to separate which output comes from which column.